# What is being inserted into this table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm not very familiar with SQL Server and T-SQL so I was trying to understand what was being inserted into this table. I think it's just field or column names being inserted since there is no `FROM` statement but the syntax looks strange to me. Obviously the one insertion is a variable. What are the 0s in front? I I've only dealt with MySQL.

```
INSERT INTO EXAMPLETABLE 
   SELECT 
       @RANDOMEVARIABLE IDTYPE, 0 foofoofoo, 0 foofoo, 0 foo
```

Answer (score 1):

One record will be inserted.  The value of `@RANDOMEVARIABLE` will be stored in the first column and 0 will be stored in the next 3 columns.  Since all of the values are constants (and one local variable) no `FROM` is required.

Note that the order and names of the columns in the `SELECT` part are irrelevant.  The data will be mapped to the column in the order they exist in the destination table (the types must be compatible as well).  For that reason it's typically better to specify the column:

```
INSERT INTO EXAMPLETABLE 
VALUES (IDTYPE, foofoofoo, foofoo, foo) 
SELECT @RANDOMEVARIABLE IDTYPE, 0 foofoofoo, 0 foofoo, 0 foo
```

You would get the same results by not supplying column aliases:

```
INSERT INTO EXAMPLETABLE 
SELECT @RANDOMEVARIABLE, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: OK. So what is the point of adding the name after 0? Couldn't they just put 0, 0, 0?

Comment: Yes - sometimes is just gives context to the data so you know what is _intended_ to get inserted.  It doesn't _hurt_ anything to have the name, but I've seen some get confused thinking that they can put the column in any order and it will map by name, which is not correct.